# Android dynamically display a downloading image

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I want to supply a good user experience,which is dynamically display a  downloading image.I mean that the bitmap should be displayed even if during the bitmap is downloaded from remote server.Some image website have this feature. For example,if I download half of bitmap data from the remote server,it can display half of the bitmap in imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **"Android-Query"** Library for Display Image from Internet. Please see my this answer and follow one by one step of **wiki page** of Android-Query

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/14827292#14827292)

All the information to display image is on Wiki Page. https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading

```
 aq.id(imageview).progress(this).image(imageUrl, true, true, **50, 0**, new BitmapAjaxCallback(){

                       @Override
                       public void callback(String url, ImageView iv, Bitmap bm, AjaxStatus status){

                           iv.setImageBitmap(bm);


                       }

               });
```

Comment: But I think this is not suitable for my requirement,I want to display the bitmap even if during the bitmap is downloaded. for example,if I download half of bitmap data from the remote server,it can display half of the bitmap in imageview.

Comment: you can use **50, 0**  for half display image . just need to give the size such as 70,0 or 120,0 etc. please try it